# Sympy functions

Tags: sympy, mathematical-optimization

I have not used sympy so far, but i feel like trying it out as it seems to be a good to define functions you want to optimize. [image], this is the function that i am trying to code with sympy. I know i could do it simply using a normal function, but it would be cool for example to code it in sympy and then it would be quite easy i would think for python to find the derivative for example. I want the sum to run over [image]
Again it's simple when using normal functions, but if anyone can help me code this function in sympy, i would appreciate it! To sum it up, i would like to code this function, and having the flexibility to let the sum run over a vector of the one such as the example i provided. Also, i am basically doing this to optimize this function using something like newton raphson method. It's just a toy example to get a feel of the algorithm. note: theta is an unknown that i will optimize over. Thanks for any hint:)!

Y

Comment: Coding it in sympy would run extremely much slower than in numpy. Sympy's strength would be to simplify functions or e.g. calculate symbolic differentials.  Whenever you need a non-obvious amount of calculations, you can use sympy's lambdify to convert it to a numpy function.  Also, to obtain helpful answers it would really help if you'd provide your functions and data in a textual form, not as images.

Comment: Have you spent much time with the sympy tutorial?  https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html

Comment: thanks johan, that's really good advice:)!

Comment: i am going to go through it soon(:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use sympy to find the derivative:

```
In [132]: x = IndexedBase('x', real=True)                                                                                                      

In [133]: n, i = symbols('n, i', integer=True, positive=True)                                                                                  

In [134]: theta = Symbol('theta', real=True)                                                                                                   

In [135]: objective = -n*log(pi) - Sum(log(1 + (x[i] - theta)**2), (i, 0, n-1))                                                                

In [136]: objective                                                                                                                            
Out[136]: 
            n - 1                      
             ___                       
             ╲                         
              ╲      ⎛           2    ⎞
-n⋅log(π) -   ╱   log⎝(-θ + x[i])  + 1⎠
             ╱                         
             ‾‾‾                       
            i = 0                      

In [137]: objective.diff(theta)                                                                                                                
Out[137]: 
 n - 1                 
  ____                 
  ╲                    
   ╲     2⋅θ - 2⋅x[i]  
    ╲  ────────────────
-   ╱             2    
   ╱   (-θ + x[i])  + 1
  ╱                    
  ‾‾‾‾                 
 i = 0
```

You can also lambdify these expressions for faster evaluation (note that I made the sum go from 0 to n-1 to match Python indexing):

```
In [138]: lambdify((theta, x, n), objective)(1, [1,2,3], 3)                                                                                    
Out[138]: -5.736774750542246
```

You can also try solving analytically for small input samples e.g.:

```
In [142]: vec = [1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                      

In [143]: objective.diff(theta).subs(n, 3).doit().subs({x[i]:vec[i] for i in range(3)})                                                        
Out[143]: 
    2⋅θ - 6        2⋅θ - 4        2⋅θ - 2   
- ──────────── - ──────────── - ────────────
         2              2              2    
  (3 - θ)  + 1   (2 - θ)  + 1   (1 - θ)  + 1

In [144]: solve(_, theta)                                                                                                                      
Out[144]: 
⎡           _____________          _____________          _____________          _____________⎤
⎢          ╱   1   √11⋅ⅈ          ╱   1   √11⋅ⅈ          ╱   1   √11⋅ⅈ          ╱   1   √11⋅ⅈ ⎥
⎢2, 2 -   ╱  - ─ - ───── , 2 +   ╱  - ─ - ───── , 2 -   ╱  - ─ + ───── , 2 +   ╱  - ─ + ───── ⎥
⎣       ╲╱     3     3         ╲╱     3     3         ╲╱     3     3         ╲╱     3     3   ⎦
```

For larger inputs an analytic solution won't work (the equation is polynomial so Abel-Ruffini limits this) but you can solve them numerically using sympy if you want:

```
In [150]: vec = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                                                                                                                

In [151]: objective.diff(theta).subs(n, 5).doit().subs({x[i]:vec[i] for i in range(5)})                                                        
Out[151]: 
    2⋅θ - 10       2⋅θ - 8        2⋅θ - 6        2⋅θ - 4        2⋅θ - 2   
- ──────────── - ──────────── - ──────────── - ──────────── - ────────────
         2              2              2              2              2    
  (5 - θ)  + 1   (4 - θ)  + 1   (3 - θ)  + 1   (2 - θ)  + 1   (1 - θ)  + 1

In [152]: nsolve(_, theta, 1)                                                                                                                  
Out[152]: 3.00000000000000
```

For large input data you will get better speed using the lambdified objective and derivative functions with something like scipy's minimize:

```
In [158]: f = lambdify((theta, x, n), -objective)                                                                                              

In [159]: fp = lambdify((theta, x, n), -objective.diff(theta))                                                                                 

In [160]: from scipy.optimize import minimize                                                                                                  

In [161]: minimize(f, 1, jac=fp, args=([1, 2, 3], 3))                                                                                          
Out[161]: 
      fun: 4.820484018668093
 hess_inv: array([[0.50002255]])
      jac: array([9.77560778e-08])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 4
      nit: 3
     njev: 4
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([2.00000005])
```

Note that the result is not as accurate as the one computed using `nsolve` though.

Also the lambdified function in this case is not as efficient as hand-written numpy code because it has not vectorised the sum:

```
In [169]: print(inspect.getsource(f))                                                                                                          
def _lambdifygenerated(theta, Dummy_167, n):
    return (n*log(pi) + (builtins.sum(log((-theta + Dummy_167[i])**2 + 1) for i in range(0, n - 1+1))))
```